# How to pass iframe url to server

Tags: html, iframe

I have a webpage where I include an IFrame:

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="http://google.com" width="800" height="500"></iframe>
```

i.e http://google.com/123

I want to pass the URL clicked within the IFrame webpage and pass it as a parameter to the server.

***Edited***
The URL can be passed as a parameter to the server  i am using python as the server side programming language

1. I want to get the URL of the object with the IFrame which is clicked
2. Pass it as a parameter to the server through form or submit method

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how you would do this, but it would help if you specify what server language you are using, I presume that you would need some JavaScript to "listen" to clicks and report that back to you server

Comment: What server-side-technique are you using? PHP?

Comment: I have edited for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
```

Your browser does not support iframes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

First of all you pass default webpages like Google.com, w3schools.com it's working now then you have to create your own dynamic or static web page.

Comment: Your answer is not understandable if you want to comment use the comment box if you are sure with your answer then answer